# SSIS Import a date and time from a txt to a table datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, ssis, type-conversion, data-conversion

So I want to import a datetime from a txt:

> 2015-01-22 09:19:59

into a table using a data flow. I have my Flat Source File and my destination DB set up fine. I changed the data type for the txt input for that column in the advanced settings and the input and output properties to:

> database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]

This is the same data type as the DB used for the table so this should work.

However, when I execute the package I get a error saying the data conversion failed... How do I make this possible?

```
[Import txt data [1743]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "statdate" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

[Import txt data [1743]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column "statdate" (2098)" failed because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "statdate" (2098)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[Import txt data [1743]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MON_Datamart\Sourcefiles\tbl_L30T1.txt" on data row 14939.
```

On the row he is giving the error the datetime is filled up with spaces. that is why on the table the "allow nulls" is checked but my SSIS package gives the error for some reason... can I somewhere tell the package to allow nulls aswell?

Comment: timestamp <> datetime

Comment: What do you mean? It says "datetime" on the data type on the table itself And when I check the mappings in the OLE DB destination the destination column says database timestamp. This worked in a DTS package (I am converting) -> timestamp = datetime

Comment: In SQL Server we have the datatypes **datetime** and **timestamp** (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx). Apologies, I didn't realise that in SSIS `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` mapped to `datetime`, as the naming convention isn't consistent with T-SQL.

Comment: Yeah I understand well it seems like it does since it clearly says "database timestamp" in the destination column on the OLE DB destination. Do you have any suggestions as to what my problem might be and how to solve it? Maybe the data conversion is fine but that error is showing up because of the spaces on certain rows in the txt file? Can I set it to accept nulls in a specific column anywhere to prevent it from throwing an error on the empty rows?

Comment: Might there be a chance that the OLE DB destination is reading the wrong data type from the table? Because the options I have for data types are this and I don't see datetime anywhere... http://imgur.com/YBNuOru So maybe it is reading only the data types SSIS knows wich doesn't include datetime

Comment: Can you dump the values of the CSV in to a varchar field temporarily so the data can be interrogated? It is possible that you have a date like `2015-02-00...` (i.e. an invalid date) or `2015-02-12 14:37:39.123456` (i.e. precision is higher than the data type allows... or similar

Comment: I would output that column as a string type from the source component and send it to a datatype conversion component with an error output, so I could see what values are not able to be converted to dates.   That would probably give a good clue as to what's going on.

Comment: gvee, like I wrote in my original question it is like this: 2015-01-22 09:19:59

Comment: Tab, I already did this but I replaced the datatype conversion by adjusting the data types inside the flat source file. This works the same and gives me the same errors (see my original question for the errors about what values fail te be converted)

Comment: I just checked the original DTS file and found out what the problem is. Some rows of the statdate column in the TXT file I am importing are empty. They do not have the value like the rest (2015-01-22 09:19:59) but instead they the row in that column is filled with SPACES. The DTS package had a activeX script to prevent these values filles with spaces to be sent to the database thus making them have the value "NULL". This is the script: If (IsDate(Trim(DTSSource("statdate")))) Then
  DTSDestination("statdate") = DTSSource("statdate")
 End If
 Main = DTSTransformStat_OK

Comment: I need a solution do detect when there are spaces instead of a timestamp and if there are spaces (string) instead of a timestamp it should NOT sent this to the OLE DB destination so it gets the value "NULL". What do I place between my flat file source and the OLE DB to intercept these spaces and sent NULL instead? I would be able to do this with a expression but how do I place a expression in between those in my DATA FLOW

Comment: If I select the column with the timestamps inside and put the error output on "ignore failure" it WORKS it sends all the timestamps to the table and the rows with spaces instead of a timestamp get ignored and he outputs "NULL" (this is the output I want)! Now I only need someone to help me and tell me how I make him ignore the rows with spaces using a expresion or whatever works in the data flow so that I don't need to put it on ingore failure since if something else then the spaces is wrong I still need it to fail so that the controll flow will make a backup of the file...

Comment: Hi Michael. To be honest, my approach would be to import in to a character field and then parse once loaded using T-SQL. But that's just my preferred methodology in ETL stuff. If you really want to deal with it on the way in using your ActiveX script then you need to expand your checking (I imagine `IsDate()` is returning true for blank values). Try: `If (IsDate(Trim(DTSSource("statdate"))) And Trim(DTSSource("startdate")) <> "" ) Then ...`. Let me know how you get on (tag me in a comment by typing *@gvee*)

Comment: You could use a TRIM() function in your data conversion and an IIF() to replace empty strings with NULL.

Comment: @gvee How would I import it to a character field and do it with T_SQL? If it works I'm open to it. However the script you provided me with would probably work but the question remains as to where I can write that script? I can't place a Script Task inside a data flow (this is only possible in the controll flow) so I don't know where to actually write that script in the data flow... Also I don't thing <> "" would work since the rows that I need to be rejected aren't empty ("") but they contain spaces. I need it to recognise spaces.

Comment: @TabAlleman Where would I enter the trim function? I can't find anywhere to put it in the data flow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it Myself. Thank you for your suggestion gvee but the way I did it is way easier.

In the Flat File Source when making a new connection in the advanced tab I fixed all the data types according to the table in the database EXCEPT the column with the timestamp (in my case it was called "statdate")! I changed this data type to a **STRING** because otherwise my Flat File Source would give me a conversion error even before any scripts would have been able to be executed and the only way arround this was setting the error output to ignore failure wich I don't want. (You still have to change the data type after you set it to a string in the advanced settings by right clicking the flat file source -> show advanced editor -> going to the output colums and changing the data type there from Date to string.)

After the timestamp was set to a string I added a Derived Column with this expression to delete all the spaces and give it then "NULL" value:

`TRIM(<YourColumnName>) == "" ? (DT_STR,4,1252)NULL(DT_STR,4,1252) : <YourColumnName>`

Next I added a Data Conversion to set the string back to a timestamp. The Data conversion is finally connected to the OLE DB Destination.

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem in the future.

End result: [Picture of data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqq7n.jpg)

Comment: Well done. You can also convert to a datetime data type directly in your expression above and save yourself an extra step.

Comment: That's exactly what I was suggesting in my comment.   Glad you figured it out.   : )   But I think you could have simply cast the derived column as a timestamp and then you wouldn't need the extra step of a Data Conversion.

Comment: What do I add at the end of my expression to skip the seperate data conversion step? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Cast the entire expression as a datetime, and set the datatype of the derived column to be DT_DBTIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you import the data in to a character field and then parse it after entry.

The following function should help you:

```
SELECT IsDate('2015-01-22 09:19:59')
     , IsDate(Current_Timestamp)
     , IsDate('          ')
     , IsDate('')
```

The `IsDate()` function returns a **1** when it *thinks* the value is a date and a **0** when it is not.

This would allow you to do something like:

```
SELECT value_as_string
     , CASE WHEN IsDate(value_as_string) = 1 THEN
         Cast(date_as_string As datetime)
       ELSE
         NULL
       END As value_as_datetime
FROM   ...
```

Comment: Please note that the `IsDate()` function isn't perfect, so [handle with care](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10807/handle-isdate-with-care.aspx)